# Billing address postal code not populated

Tags: civicontribute

If I select an item from a priceset on a contribution form, the billing address appears, but the postcode is not populated even though it is in the contact record.

Any ideas? Ta

Comment: Civi version? A standard civi contribution form? Payment processor? The billing address can be mangled by the payment processor, so be sure to test with other payment processors.